# Data sent from Ajax to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a username from the view to the controller through Ajax like this :

```
 $('#exampleFormControlSelect1').change(function(){
     var  username =$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Panier/loadPanier",
            data: {username: username},
            success: function(result){
                $("#tbodyid").empty();
                var data1 = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(data1) ;
            },

        });

    });
```

and I try to use the sent value to do some work:

```
    public function loadPanier()
{

    $res = [];
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $panier_data = $this->model_panier->getPanierData($username);

    foreach ($panier_data as $k => $v) {
        $idPiece = $v['idPiece'];
        $qte = $v['quantity'];
        $piece_data = (array)$this->model_catalogue->getDetail($idPiece);

        $price = (int)$piece_data['Unit Price'];
        $montant = $qte * $price;

        array_push($res, array(
            'idPiece' => $idPiece,
            'Description' => $piece_data['Description'],
            'qte' => $qte,
            'prix HT' => round($piece_data['Unit Price'], 3),
            'montant' => $montant
        ));
    }

    return $res;
}
```

In my URL I'm getting this error :

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

but here's what I'm noticing by doing var_dump($username):

> C:\wamp64\www\PortalDealer\application\controllers\Panier.php:66:null

So my data is not passing!

Can you help me with this?

**EDIT**
[image]

showcase the result of this part of the code :

```
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    $res = [];
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
        var_dump($username);
    $panier_data = $this->model_panier->getPanierData($username);
    var_dump($panier_data);
```

Comment: are you sure that you're not missing closing semicolon in line : `var  username =$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val()` ?

Comment: No I fixed that but I still get the null value when executing var_dump

Comment: What about in the devtool's network tab, when you're sending the request, did the request sending the correct `post` parameter?

Comment: yes it's sending the right parameter

Comment: so it's sending the `username` post data with its value? could you try `var_dump($_REQUEST)` at the controller and see the result?

Comment: The function $this->input->post returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist. Maybe you send an empty parameter or not with that name

Comment: @HastaDhana I got an empty array when I did `var_dump($_REQUEST)` but in the network header tab I get the exact username value that I select in my select options

Comment: @MikeFoxtech I'm not sending an empty parameter I check the network tab and It shows that it's sending a correct data

Comment: maybe you have a wrong controller? or maybe a problem with the routing?

Comment: try **url: "/panier/loadPanier",**

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

 - This is your error, which means, your `$panier_data` isn't array. do `var_dump($panier_data)` and check if that's the data you expected to see

Comment: Not it's not a routing problem and I tried the url but didn't work

Comment: @LIGHT I believe that it generates this error when the element inside foreach is empty and since i use the parameter to retrieve data that I'm putting in `$panier_data` so It must be empty too since the first one is empty

Comment: No, that also generates this error if the datatype is different for the element inside `foreach()`. You need to do `var_dump()` for `$panier_data` before going thru with the `foreach()` and post the result as update so we can go further here

Comment: It's null too ! but I Have to start fixing the problem with the parameter which is passing as null

Comment: could you try replacing your javascript with the one in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196107/discussion-between-light-and-m-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should send your data to `Panier/loadPanier/`.

```
$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').change(function(){
    var  val1 =$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "Panier/loadPanier/",
        data: { username: val1}
    }).done(function( result ) {
        $("#tbodyid").empty();
        var data1 = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(data1) ;
    });
});
```

You were seeing `null` every time you did `var_dump()` because you were trying to load the page independently. The page will only give you the POST value if you are going to the page thru the form, in this case, the form is javascript. When you load a page with `POST` method in javascript, the response is sent to the same page with `ajax` so you can work with your code without having to refresh the page.

Also: You cannot `return` data to javascript. You have to print it out to client side so that your javascript's JSON parser can read it. Therefore, instead of `return $res;` :

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: still giving the same result. you can see the edited post